# I am facing an error while stroring the ML model information in MLFLOW dagshub

Tags: mlflow, dagshub

Error I getting

Elasticnet model (alpha=0.500000, l1_ratio=0.500000):
RMSE: 0.793164022927685
MAE: 0.6271946374319586
R2: 0.10862644997792636
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "example.py", line 85, in 
mlflow.sklearn.log_model(lr, "model", registered_model_name="ElasticnetWineModel")
File "D:\DeepCNNClassifier\krishna\lib\site-packages\mlflow\sklearn_*init*_.py", line 393, in log_model
return Model.log(
File "D:\DeepCNNClassifier\krishna\lib\site-packages\mlflow\models\model.py", line 304, in log
mlflow.register_model(
File "D:\DeepCNNClassifier\krishna\lib\site-packages\mlflow\tracking_model_registry\fluent.py", line 67, in register_model
raise e
File "D:\DeepCNNClassifier\krishna\lib\site-packages\mlflow\tracking_model_registry\fluent.py", line 58, in register_model
create_model_response = client.create_registered_model(name)
File "D:\DeepCNNClassifier\krishna\lib\site-packages\mlflow\tracking\client.py", line 1658, in create_registered_model
return self._get_registry_client().create_registered_model(name, tags, description)
File "D:\DeepCNNClassifier\krishna\lib\site-packages\mlflow\tracking_model_registry\client.py", line 59, in create_registered_model
return self.store.create_registered_model(name, tags, description)
File "D:\DeepCNNClassifier\krishna\lib\site-packages\mlflow\store\model_registry\rest_store.py", line 83, in c`your text`reate_registered_model
response_proto = self._call_endpoint(CreateRegisteredModel, req_body)
File "D:\DeepCNNClassifier\krishna\lib\site-packages\mlflow\store\model_registry\rest_store.py", line 64, in _call_endpoint
return call_endpoint(self.get_host_creds(), endpoint, method, json_body, response_proto)
File "D:\DeepCNNClassifier\krishna\lib\site-packages\mlflow\utils\rest_utils.py", line 256, in call_endpoint
response = verify_rest_response(response, endpoint)
File "D:\DeepCNNClassifier\krishna\lib\site-packages\mlflow\utils\rest_utils.py", line 185, in verify_rest_response
raise RestException(json.loads(response.text))
mlflow.exceptions.RestException: INTERNAL_ERROR: Response: {'error': 'unsupported endpoint, please contact support@dagshub.com'}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use mlflow==2.2.2 version and your error will be gone.